# how to I make sure that only one servlet(not instance) is call at a time?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have an application which makes lot of multiple servlet calls. How do I make sure that till a particular servlet X processing is completed no other servlet instance of Y, Z is called.

A SingleThreadModel or synchronization will make sure that only one thread per servlet is called. However that may not work on more than one servlet.

Comment: Each servlet can add a flag to a application context key and you can have a filter which checks this property.

Comment: Why would you require that *someone* make a certain HTTP request that uses servlet X, before *everybody else* is allowed to use all the other pages of your system, using servlets Y, Z, ...? That makes no sense.

Comment: I have a scenario where I want to wipe out a session by clearing cookies. While I clear cookies using a servlet, I want to make sure that another servlet doesn't carry fwd that.

Comment: cookies are kept client-side. So clearing them in two clients at the same time should be no problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Callback mechanism for each server calls. Onsuccess of first server call you can call second.

Comment: exactly how I implemented it.

 function successCallback(response) {
if(condition){
call another servlet.
}

works

Answer (score 0):

You could implement manual synchronization by defining your own locks.

For Example declare a static Object to use as semaphore:

```
public static final Object MY_LOCK = new Object();
```

and where you want to synchronize you could use it like that:

```
public void someMethod() {
    synchronized(MY_LOCK) {
        // do stuff that may not be called at same time
    }
}

public void someOtherMethod() {
    synchronized(MY_LOCK) {
        // do other stuff that may not be called at same time
    }
}
```

That way you can use the same Lock in different Methods (or servlets in your case).

Comment: But I must say, it is hard to imagine why you would want to do that. It is feasible, but highly unusual.